# Could you give me a working, dangerous LaTeX input file to test the vulnerability of my server?

Tags: filesystem-access, write-file

I have an IIS web server on which I installed Miktex distribution.

I host a site that allows users to submit LaTeX input codes. The server then compiles the input using `pdflatex.exe` to produce a pdf file.

For those who understand C#, here is the code snippet:

```cs
    Process p = new Process();

    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);

    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-interaction=nonstopmode " + inputpath;
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\mydomain.com\working";

    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdflatex.exe";

    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

My site runs under `ApplicationPoolIdentity` with `Load User Profile = True`. As far as I know, this account has less privilege.

Shortly speaking, I want to test this server by submitting a dangerous input file.

Could you give me a working, dangerous LaTeX input file to test the vulnerability of my server?

Note: Please don't use javascript and HTML because I am not interested to think of XSS and XSRF now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not try the one given in [Listing 1](https://cs.ucsd.edu/~scheckow/papers/tex2010/tex2010.pdf)? It's not complete, but the only part missing is 11 lines of the JScript it runs at next login.

Comment: The link is broken.